# Picasso Not Downloading High Resolution Image

Tags: android

I have 3 URLs on gridview and only 2 of the 3 images load into the ImageView.

I am using Picaso:

```
Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).fit().centerCrop().into(ivPicture);
```

I have also tried to skip caching:

```
Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).fit().centerCrop().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).into(ivPicture);
```

Additional Info of image:

- Width 2048 / Height 1371 pixels
- File size = 224KB
- File format is JPG

When I use Picasso's `.resize(h w)`to a lower the resolution eg: resize (100 100) for testing the image is downloaded but the aspect ration is not kept as some images will have a 9:6 ratio or vice versa 6:9 or a perfect square 5:5 and therefore I do not want to resize any images to a fixed ratio instead I use `.fit().centerCrop()` which works very well except for this 1 high-res image, Picasso just loads on the placeholder endlessly without any errors, I can understand if the pixels are too many but the file size is quite small in size I don't know why Picasso is struggling to download a +/- 200KB image.

Is there a way for Picasso to compress images over certain pixels perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso can not process very big images because will receive out of memory .You must to do image transformation inside native code .Not in java

Comment: I think I will compress the images upon user upload so that picasso can access them already compressed, I will get to that part when I write my registration and gallery upload class for images, I have used it on one of my previous apps, hope all the methods and libraries are still available and still up to date